# How to sort a Map with Erlang?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, erlang

I have a map of format "Player Name : Score".

I am trying to sort it by score (i.e. the value)

Is this possible?

Comment: Maps in Erlang are unordered so it doesn't make sense to sort a Map to a Map. Do you want a sorted List as the final result? In that case you can use `maps:to_list/1` and then `lists:keysort/2`.

Comment: I realised that Maps are unordered after I put up the question. *Facepalm* Yes thank you for your help appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map elements are not ordered, so first convert to a list of pairs, then sort on the second element of the tuple:

```
1> Map = #{alice => 20, bob => 7, chi => 99, danielle => 22}.
#{alice => 20,bob => 7,chi => 99,danielle => 22}
2> List = maps:to_list(Map).
[{alice,20},{bob,7},{chi,99},{danielle,22}]
3> lists:keysort(2, List).
[{bob,7},{alice,20},{danielle,22},{chi,99}]
```